# How to apply custom CSS and Javascript specific CMS page Magento

Tags: javascript, css, layout, magento-1.9

I want to add `lightbox` for playing videos on my one specific CMS page. I placed my CSS file in `JS/MY THEME/JQUERY/PLUGIN/VENOBOX/CSS/myfile.css` and JS files in `JS/MY THEME/jquery/plugins/venobox/js/myfile.js`, but it didn't works. I am doing everything, but not working.

I  use the following code in Layout Update XML of my CMS page:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>js_css</type>
        <name>smartwave/jquery/plugins/venobox/css/html5boxplayer.css</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>
            smartwave/jquery/plugins/venobox/js/html5lightbox.js
        </script>
    </action>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>
            smartwave/jquery/plugins/venobox/js/jquery.js
        </script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Please help if someone has implemented this features. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For css you need to include the files in xml file as following:

```
<action method="addItem">
   <type>skin_css</type>
   <name>css/html5boxplayer.css</name>
</action>
```

For js you need to do the same operation as following:

```
<action method="addItem">
   <type>skin_js</type>
   <name>js/html5lightbox.js</name>
</action>
```

Pay attention for type declaration. Of course all the files should be placed on their specific folder under your theme.

Comment: venobox css js and some .gif assets i locate these css and js but where to locate .gif in which folder

Comment: media files (like .gif) are located in `media` folder

Comment: thanks it works there was a little issue that was using $ in my inland script i just replaced this with jquerry and it works

Comment: Yes, this is because in magento the standard javascript framework is Prototype, and the `$` is reserved to this.